# Given a non-relational no-lookup User id stored on the Opportunity, is there a formula to get this user?

Tags: formula-field

Someone added a field called `OwnerId` to the Opportunity. It seems to be a text field with no lookup to the User object, even though it is holding a User id.

I tried to build a new formula field on Opportunity, a `WorkersId` field that would pull the `EmployeeId` from the User object. But I couldn't do this as a formula because the `OwnerId` field wasn't a real relationship field.

I'm curious if I have to write some Apex code to copy the `EmployeeId` from the User to the Opportunity or is there a formula that can still do this?

Comment: May I know, Why you can't get `EmployeeId` from `User` object directly by creating the formula field's using the formula as `Owner.employeeId__c`  in Opportunity object(Field EmployeeId's API name can be varied in your situation)?

Comment: I don't know know why, that's what I'm confused about. At least in the "formula builder" there is no "Owner" there is only an "OwnerId" and it does not allow me to look up anything on the User.

Comment: "CreatedBy" and "LastModifiedBy" both work the way I expect, they link to a User so I can pull in details from those User objects. But OwnerId does not work that way.

Comment: In your formula field page, Can you click `Advanced formula` section and check `Opportunity Owner>` option in dropdown by Clicking `Insert field` Button?

Comment: A formula field can never result in a Lookup, but can store the text for an ID from a lookup/master detail/Id field (this is probably why you see it this way). The only way to then use this to be a lookup-like, clickable value is to create a component (e.g. LWC) that presents it that way. There's nothing out-of-the-box in Salesforce that will let you treat that text as a clickable link to a record. (Other than some URL-based button that builds the URL using this field's value.)

Comment: A formula field can render a URL that is clickable based on ID.

Comment: if you want the faux-relationship to be read only when a record is viewed in the UX, you could create an additional component on the record page via screen flow, LWC, or even Visualforce to display the value by doing SOQL.

Comment: Mohanraj Sivalingam, there is no Owner on the Opportunity object, there is only OwnerId. Again, Created By and Last Modified By works the way I expect, but OwnerId does not.